# Binary search on file with different line length

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have some code which does a binary search over a file with sorted hex values (SHA1 hashes) on each line. This is used to search the [HaveIBeenPwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) database. The latest version contains a count of the number of times each password hash was found, so some lines have extra characters at the end, in the format ':###'

The length of this additional check isn't fixed, and it isn't always there. This causes the buffer to read incorrect values and fail to find values that actually exist.

Current code:

```
static bool Check(string asHex, string filename)
{
    const int LINELENGTH = 40;  //SHA1 hash length

    var buffer = new byte[LINELENGTH];
    using (var sr = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        //Number of lines
        var high = (sr.Length / (LINELENGTH + 2)) - 1;
        var low = 0L;

        while (low <= high)
        {
            var middle = (low + high + 1) / 2;
            sr.Seek((LINELENGTH + 2) * ((long)middle), SeekOrigin.Begin);
            sr.Read(buffer, 0, LINELENGTH);
            var readLine = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            switch (readLine.CompareTo(asHex))
            {
                case 0:
                    return true;

                case 1:
                    high = middle - 1;
                    break;

                case -1:
                    low = middle + 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My idea is to seek forward from the middle until a newline character is found, then seek backwards for the same point, which should give me a complete line which I can split by the ':' delimiter. I then compare the first part of the split string array which should be just a SHA1 hash.

I think this should still centre on the correct value, however I am wondering if there is a neater way to do this? If the midpoint isn't that actual midpoint between the end of line characters, should it be adjusted before the high and low values are?

Comment: Sounds like maybe it might be easier to normalize (by padding each line/entry) the file first.   Or, maybe you could also generate a seperate index file that contains the starting location (seek offset) of each line/entry.

Comment: I had considered just going through the file and removing all the hash counts, but ideally I want it to work on the file the file provided rather than my own version.

Comment: The the index should work.  Give it the same file name with a .index suffix and only generate it if the password file is newer.  Using a binary will make each entry the same size (file position is a long) and should make it fast to read.   You run your binary search on the index and lookup the current password hash be seeking and reading from the passwords file.

Comment: So you are suggesting to create another file without the counts at the end of some lines?

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: 30GB uncompressed

Comment: Got it. So loading it all to memory is out of the question, and small record sizes mean an index is likely to be nearly as big as the data. You may want to consider a pass of the file to "chunk" it into manageable-sized pieces. If you group based on the first two characters, and assume a relatively even distribution (hash values _should_ be evenly distributed), that's 256 files of about 120MB each. Or maybe you can just index the start of the each new leading hex character, to make scanning faster. Even generating an index will be slow, but if you'll be doing a lot of searches it might pay off

Comment: @MikeS159 I was suggesting that you create an index file that contains the starting position of each line in the passwords file.   This problem interested me so I looked into it a bit more, I will post a POSSIBLE solution in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I THINK this may be a possible simpler (faster) solution without the backtracking to the beginning of the line.  I think you can just use byte file indexes instead of trying to work with a full "record/line.  Because the middle index will not always be at the start of a line/record, the "readline" can return a partial line/record.  If you were to immediately do a second "readline", you would get a full line/record.  It wouldn't be quite optimal, because you would actually be comparing a little ahead of the middle index.

I downloaded the pwned-passwords-update-1 and pulled out about 30 records at the start, end, and in the middle, it seemed to find them all.  What do you think?

```
const int HASHLENGTH = 40;

static bool Check(string asHex, string filename)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        var low = 0L;
        // We don't need to start at the very end
        var high = fs.Length - (HASHLENGTH - 1); // EOF - 1 HASHLENGTH

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        while (low <= high)
        {
            var middle = (low + high + 1) / 2;
            fs.Seek(middle, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Resync with base stream after seek
            sr.DiscardBufferedData();

            var readLine = sr.ReadLine();

            // 1) If we are NOT at the beginning of the file, we may have only read a partial line so
            //    Read again to make sure we get a full line.
            // 2) No sense reading again if we are at the EOF
            if ((middle > 0) && (!sr.EndOfStream)) readLine = sr.ReadLine() ?? "";

            string[] parts = readLine.Split(':');
            string hash = parts[0];

            // By default string compare does a culture-sensitive comparison we may not be what we want?
            // Do an ordinal compare (0-9 < A-Z < a-z)
            int compare = String.Compare(asHex, hash, StringComparison.Ordinal);

            if (compare < 0)
            {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
            else if (compare > 0)
            {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I though this wasn't working, but it turned out there was a version that was sorted by count rather than the has value, causing the search to fail.
I have just tested it by reading each hash and finding it in the file using your function and it worked for every value!
Thank you

Comment: My suggestion is to DiscardBufferedData just before the seek rather than after.  I've seen strange results debugging when the discard is done after the seek.  Specifically, seek clears EndOfStream but it can get set again by DiscardBufferedData (even though the seek is not to end-of-file).  This causes the read to fail (it returns a null value).  To me, this seems like a bug but the workaround is simple.

Comment: Two special cases exist for the "double-read" approach. 1) beginning of file (dealt with here); 2) end-of-file (not fully dealt with here). If sr.EndOfStream is true when the line is split, part[0] length must be checked. If shorter than the hash length, it must be handled same as a "high" read (high=middle+1 and continue). Adding this check eliminates the need for reducing the file length by HASHLENGTH at the beginning. That's a good thing because HASHLENGTH is not the length of a line, only part of a line, so its effect is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving your problem was to create a new binary file containing the hashes only.  16 byte/hash and a faster binary search  ( I don't have 50 reps needed to comment only )